# How to access controller ActionBindingContext in rc2 vnext?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

In rc1 and previous builds, a controller had a BindingContext property, which was an ActionBindingContext object.

This doesnt seem to be available in rc2?  Any ideas how to access it?

I am using rc2-16357

My nuget feeds are

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <packageSources>
        <add key="aspnet-contrib" value="https://www.myget.org/F/aspnet-contrib/api/v3/index.json" />
        <add key="AspNetVNext" value="https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v3/index.json" />
        <add key="AzureAd Nightly" value="https://www.myget.org/F/azureadwebstacknightly/api/v3/index.json" />
        <add key="NuGet" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
        <add key="DotNetCore" value="https://www.myget.org/F/dotnet-core/api/v3/index.json" />
        <add key="XUnit" value="https://www.myget.org/F/xunit/api/v3/index.json" />
    </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

Comment: **RC2 is not yet published.** What version/build you use exactly? The state of preliminary RC2 now is very unstable. You should describe exactly which NuGet feeds (URLs) you use. Different NuGet feeds provides different versions of ASP.NET packages now.

Comment: You should share some demo project which can be build with the latest pre-release of RC2. At me all standard pre-release of RC2 either can't be build now or can't be started.